# Configuring router to assign the same DHCP IP address to a device

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ip-address

Can I configure my Netgear router to always assign the same DHCP IP address to a computer with name "xxxxx"?

That also means reserving that IP if the computer is not online, and not assigning it to another computer.

Comment: I can on mine, but it will depend upon which netgear router you have!

Please supply us with the model number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to reserve "static" DHCP addresses based on the network card's MAC address.  I don't think I've ever seen reservations based on name.

For example, on the [Netgear WNDR3300's](http://interface.netgear-forum.com/WNDR3300/) home page, you'd go to `Advanced -> LAN Setup -> Address Reservation`.  For the [FVS336g](http://tools.netgear.com/landing/gui/security/fvs336g/simulators/v_2.2.0_59.9/lan_groups.htm), it's under `Network -> LAN Setup -> LAN Groups`.

If you're trying to assign the same IP to different computers you are not expecting to be on the LAN simultaneously, I suppose you could trick the router by spoofing the MAC's to match.  Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

With out the router model it is almost impossible to answer you.
Netgear recently started releasing very low spec'd routers with many features removed along with their mid-range models. It is most likely not possible but give us the model and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Something that you can do on every router is to restrict the range of attribued IP by the DHCP. And so set your computer with a static IP outside of the DHCP range